# Using toRoute() outside controller ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What I want:

If session is not set, I want to redirect to `zf2.localhost/authUser/index`

When I'm using `toRoute` in CreatorController everything works.

However, I want to use this method in several files.  When I attempt to call `toRoute` in my SessionServiceController, I get the following error.

> Error:
>   Url plugin requires that controller event compose a router; none found

Could you write me what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

*CreatorController (zf2.localhost/creator/index)*

```
   <?php
    namespace Creator\Controller;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Creator\Controller\SessionServiceController;

    class CreatorController extends AbstractActionController{

        public function __construct(){
            $this -> sessionService = new SessionServiceController();
        }

        public function indexAction(){
            if($this-> sessionService ->checkSession()){
                echo 'Witam';
            }
        }
    }
```

*SessionServiceController*:

```
<?php
namespace Creator\controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Creator\Controller\SessionServiceController;

class SessionServiceController extends AbstractActionController {

    const CONTAINER_SESSION_ID = 'usr_id';

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> session_id = new Container( self::CONTAINER_SESSION_ID);
    }

    public function checkSession(){
        if (empty($this ->session_id->usr_id)){
            //$this->redirect()->toUrl("zf2.localhost/authUser/index");
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('creator/default',
                array('controller'=>'authUser', 'action'=>'index'));
        }  

        if (!empty($this ->session_id->usr_id)){
            return true;
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: I have clarified your intent.  It would appear that you're having inconsistent results calling a method and I wanted to highlight that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to directly instantiate your controllers, use the ServiceManager. For toRoute to work, the Url helper needs a instance of the router. This is usually handled by the ControllerPluginManager when a controller is called from the ControllerManager.

But, beyond that, this logic is probably in the wrong place. If you're checking for authenticated users, you probably want to load and utilize zend's authentication service in an event before the controller is even loaded. I would guess the best place is somewhere in your ON_ROUTE event loop, but I can't speak to your specific application.

You will know if a user is logged in or not very early in the request chain, no reason to boot a controller. Take a peek at ZfcUser (https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser), it already has versions of auth redirect listeners you can use as inspiration for your own (or you might find you just want to use that project for what you're doing)